# Regex to find five consecutive consonants

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex for python that finds words with five consecutive consonants.

These words would work -

```
tnortvcvni (rtvcvn)
kahjdflka (hjdflk)
```

But these words wouldn't (no five letters in row without vowels) -

```
peanut 
butter
jelly
```

Comment: Upped as this could be useful in the context of Stack Overflow being a Q & A archive (and I can't find an **exact** duplicate).

Comment: To make this question better, it would be good to show us what you have tried so far: [Questions asking for \[homework\] help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you don't mean a fixed length of 5 characters but a minimum:

```
(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z]){5,}
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/SW5Wdt/1)

Note: set `i` flag if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

`.*[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]{5}.*` is one way, assuming lower case letters.

You'll do well to find a word in English that has 5 consecutive consonants, although there are a few, e.g. "catchphrase" or even the maddening "tsktsks".

Comment: A bit shorter if lookaheads are supported: `(?![a-z]*[aeiou])[a-z]{5}`

Comment: @revo: My, that's posh. You might as well put the `(i)` thing in for case-insensitivity. (My reg-ex knowledge doesn't go much beyond `grep` in the 1990s.)

Comment: It's not clear what OP wants indeed. They talk about strings of 5 character long but what is there as output has 6 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like (assuming `y` is a vowel)

```
[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]{5}
```

Comment: Sure. Wouldn't the other way be better — to add y's to the range?

Comment: Despite the OP saying "python", this is asked on only the regex tag, so therefore it's appropriate to have a variety of answers targeting varying level of sophistication.

Answer (score 1):

You can just exclude all the vowels, lower and uppercase, and exclude every other character ***NOT*** belonging to a word (using `\W`)

```
\w*[^aeiouAEIOU\W]{5}\w*
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0OLXpx/3)**

---

Even better, work with the case-insensitive flag and communicate only the lowercase letters

```
(?i)\w*[^aeiou\W]{5}\w*
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ft4u4D/4)**

Comment: Your are missing `\d_` and could drop one of the cases by use of the case-insensitivity flag

Comment: @SebastianProske You're right indeed. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to express the all consonants term inside a character class (all assuming case insensitivity):

- simply lisiting them all `[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]`
- listing them all with ranges `[b-df-hj-pq-tv-z]`
- using a negated character class `[^\W\d_aeiou]` (doesn't work properly with full-Unicode support for \w)

Take one of those and simply add `{5}` to match it 5 times. If you want to match the full word instead of the 5-consonants-part only, also match the letters around, e.g. `[a-z]*[b-df-hj-pq-tv-z][a-z]*`

You can also use lookaheads to do this (if supported, python does), e.g. `(?=[^aeiou]{5})[a-z]{5,}` to match a sequenze of 5 non-vowels that are letters at the same time. Same can be done with a lookbehind, e.g. `[a-z]{5}(?<=[^aeiou]{5})`.